# Is there a workaround to use percentage values for Region's width and height in CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

It would be very convenient if we could use percentage values in CSS for Region's width and height, but the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) states that:

> Percentage values are not useful since the actual value would be computed from the width and/or height of the Regions's parent before the parent is laid out.

So is there a workaround for this? I tried to use [`Platform.runLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) to request a layout pass after the parent is loaded to the scene, but nothing happened:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml")));
    scene.getStylesheets().setAll(getClass().getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

**main.fxml**

```
<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
           xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
           fx:controller="Controller">
  <Region fx:id="child"
          styleClass="child"/>
</StackPane>
```

**styles.css**

```
.root {
  -fx-pref-width: 500px;
  -fx-pref-height: 500px;
}

.child {
  -fx-background-color: teal;
  -fx-pref-width: 50%;
  -fx-pref-height: 50%;
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
  @FXML
  private Region child;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> if (child != null) child.requestLayout());
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope, not possible. Every node provides the properties it supports and the parser to use itself. Implementing this kind of functionality would require you to rewrite all node types (even node types in foreign libraries that you do not know about.  Note that `GridPane` does provide some similar functionality via row/column constraints and you could extend `GridPane` to allow specifying those in CSS e.g. as commaseperated list or you could write your own layout doing something similar...

Comment: Also note that there is a cyclic dependency here. The `StackPane` is trying to find out how much space the children needs before it decides on its own size, while your child tries to adjust its size based on how big that `StackPane` is. So, without talking about what the API *could* do, think about how *you* want to layout them - you need to break out of this cyclic dependency by making one of them decide on its own size. When you are clear on that, then you look for how the API could achieve that.

Comment: @fabian Can we determine if the specified value in CSS was in percentage `%` format because it always return the equivalent decimal value in actual code (e.g `50%` is always `0.5`)? I might use a _custom layout_ as a _workaround_ if I could distinguish the value between percentage `%` and decimal.